# The word after among in a sentece

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which sentence is grammatically correct?:

America has one of the highest obesity rates ***among other*** developed countries

or

America has one of the highest obesity rates ***among*** developed countries

or

America has one of the highest obesity rates ***among the*** developed countries

Comment: They are all completely grammatical, and not significantly different in meaning.. The second is the most natural.

Comment: I would argue that the first one is not correct. America is not one of the **other** developed countries (assuming it to mean 'other than America' and not 'other than a country previously mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

> America has one of the highest obesity rates among other developed countries

> America has one of the highest obesity rates among developed countries

> America has one of the highest obesity rates among the developed countries

The 2nd example is the most natural, and I agree with Kate that the 1st example is incorrect; America is not **among** **other** countries.